# What version control workflow should be used for maintaining HTML/CSS/JS version with ASP.net version of web app?

Tags: git, web-applications, workflow, frontend, branching-strategy

I'm a web designer who puts together the HTML/CSS/JS for front-end web app design.  I work with another developer who takes my designs and develops a functional web app from those designs utilizing ASP.net.

In my mind there are three versions of the web app - my initial HTML/CSS/JS design, the other developer's ASP.net version, and the version that is on the live website.

Any advice on how to set this up in Git?  I'm planning on using two repos, one for my front-end designs, and another for the ASP.net development and live version of the website (for the branches I plan on using this git branching model (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Is there any benefit to having them all be different branches in the same repo?  My main concern is insuring that we have ASP.net versions of the website seperated from the HTML/CSS/JS original design, while ensuring that both are in an identical state (apart from functionality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your static HTML-CSS mockups I can't see any reasons to be in the same repo, as ASP-code

- they are sources of, not independent parallel work
- Branching branch entire repo, you'll just got additional clones of single entity "current design"

LIVE and DEV versions of code fit into branching workflow a lot better and 2 independent repos is, in common, right direction - for linking changesets to Mockup-repo from ASP-repo hash of Mockup-changeset with changed design can be used in commit message of ASP-changeset